# how can i make scrolling text in c(right to left)

Tags: c, scroll

1-                                       hello world<---hello world<---hello world

My purpose is moving text end of line to beginning of line?
Can someone help?

Comment: Please show some effort. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing website. It is a site where we answer specific questions about a specific problem.

Comment: Considering that most terminals these days are 80 columns wide, you could have a single string of 80 characters that you print over and over again, erasing the line between the prints. Just modify the string you print accordingly. How to erase the line depends on your system and terminal program.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you tell what are your the input and output strings?

Comment: @mdatsev you are right but belive me i dont have any idea about this algorithm.I dont wanna specially all code.I just wanna get ideas about what can i do...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help with [certain problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://www.google.com). Read [stack overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Literaly googled your title and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139892/scrolling-text-in-c